# Кнопка установки начального значения для счетчика

Tags: javascript

Всем, добрый день!
Никак не могу найти решение проблемы.

Имеется простой счетчик, который считает клики по кнопке Clicker, а также кнопка Reset, которая обнуляет значения. Все работает, кроме кнопки 'Set a number' - ее задача получить значение из input и начать отсчет от него.
Или более конкретный вопрос - как значение переменной inputField передать в качестве параметра в set: function (value)?

```js
var clickBtn = document.getElementById('clicker');
var resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset');
var setBtn = document.getElementById('set');
var resultInner = document.getElementById('clickAmmount');
var inputField = +document.getElementById('setValue').value;


function makeCounter() {

  var currentCount = 1;

  return {
    getNext: function() {
      resultInner.textContent = currentCount;
      return currentCount++;
    },

    set: function(value) {
      currentCount = value;
    },

    reset: function() {
      currentCount = 0;
      resultInner.textContent = currentCount;
    }
  };
}

var counter = makeCounter();

clickBtn.addEventListener('click', counter.getNext);
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', counter.reset);
setBtn.addEventListener('click', counter.set);
```

```html
<p class="textInner">
  Clicks Ammount: <span id="clickAmmount">0</span>
</p>
<button id="clicker">Ckicker</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
<p>Init number:</p>
<input id="setValue" type="number" value="0">
<button id="set">Set a number</button>
```

Comment: Объект счетчика лучше помещать в свойство элемента - это сделает код чище, даст возможность работы с контекстом, и избавит от ряда сложностей. А если в документе возможно несколько элементов со счетчиком, то разумно будет написать объектный класс (и всю логику инициализации и назначения листенеров перенести в конструктор).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нужно заранее получать значение поля - это скаляр, он не имеет отношения к будущему значению, храните само поле.
В сеттере получаете `inputField.value`.

```js
var clickBtn = document.getElementById('clicker');
var resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset');
var setBtn = document.getElementById('set');
var resultInner = document.getElementById('clickAmmount');
var inputField = document.getElementById('setValue');


function makeCounter() {

  var currentCount = 1;

  return {
    getNext: function() {
      resultInner.textContent = currentCount;
      return currentCount++;
    },

    set: function() {
      currentCount = inputField.value;
      resultInner.textContent = currentCount;
    },

    reset: function() {
      currentCount = 0;
      resultInner.textContent = currentCount;
    }
  };
}

var counter = makeCounter();

clickBtn.addEventListener('click', counter.getNext);
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', counter.reset);
setBtn.addEventListener('click', counter.set);
```

```html
<p class="textInner">
  Clicks Ammount: <span id="clickAmmount">0</span>
</p>
<button id="clicker">Ckicker</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
<p>Init number:</p>
<input id="setValue" type="number" value="0">
<button id="set">Set a number</button>
```

Второй вариант - определить корректные обработчики событий:

```js
var clickBtn = document.getElementById('clicker');
var resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset');
var setBtn = document.getElementById('set');
var resultInner = document.getElementById('clickAmmount');
var inputField = document.getElementById('setValue');


function makeCounter(viewEl) {
  var currentCount = 0;
  return {
    getNext() { return this.set(1 + currentCount);},
    set(value) {
      currentCount = +value;
      viewEl.textContent = currentCount;
      return currentCount;
    },
    reset() { this.set(0);}
  };
}

var counter = makeCounter(resultInner);

clickBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {counter.getNext();});
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {counter.reset();});
setBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {counter.set(inputField.value);});
```

```html
<p class="textInner">
  Clicks Ammount: <span id="clickAmmount">0</span>
</p>
<button id="clicker">Ckicker</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
<p>Init number:</p>
<input id="setValue" type="number" value="0">
<button id="set">Set a number</button>
```